# Get the string between first two \ and \

Tags: python

i have some strings like

```
mystrinng=\Mango\stone\forest\
mystrinng=\Orange\sand\house\
mystrinng=\Rabbit\cage\village\
```

I want to get only the first string

```
Mango
Orange
Rabbit
```

I got the strings using the below code.Is there any better way to do this other than the below code

```
    if(mystrinng.startswith('\\')):
                objname=mystrinng[1:].split('\\')[0]
```

Comment: `objname=mystrinng.split('\\')[1]` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
In [8]: a = ['\\Mango\\stone\\forest\\', '\\Orange\\sand\\house\\', '\\Rabbit\\cage\\village\\']
In [11]: [x.split('\\')[1] for x in a]
Out[11]: ['Mango', 'Orange', 'Rabbit']
```